# Makefile always execute default command irrespctive of CFLAGS

Tags: makefile, mingw

I am currently building msp430 gcc based c plus plus program using minGW and conemu console.
    SUPPORT_FILE_DIRECTORY = "/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include"

```
SOURCES=blink.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEVICE  = msp430g2553
CC      = msp430-elf-gcc
GDB     = msp430-elf-gdb

CFLAGS = -I $(SUPPORT_FILE_DIRECTORY) -mmcu=$(DEVICE) -O2 -g
LFLAGS = -L $(SUPPORT_FILE_DIRECTORY)

all: ${OBJECTS}
        $(CC) $(SOURCES) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $(DEVICE).out

clean:
        rm $(OBJECTS)
```

if I run make with just print I always get following output

```
$ make --just-print
g++    -c -o blink.o blink.cpp
msp430-elf-gcc blink.cpp -I "/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include" -mmcu=msp430g2553 -O2 -g -L "/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include" -o msp430g2553.out
```

And actual make fail with following error

```
g++    -c -o blink.o blink.cpp
    blink.cpp:21:20: fatal error: msp430.h: No such file or directory
     #include <msp430.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    mingw32-make: *** [<builtin>: blink.o] Error 1
```

Additional observation made is if object file is already present then this error do not occurs.

Comment: This isn't clear - what command do you *want* Make to run?

Comment: I want to run only msp430-elf-gcc blink.cpp -I "/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include" -mmcu=msp430g2553 -O2 -g -L "/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include" -o msp430g2553.out

Comment: Have you verified that `/c/ti/msp430_gcc/include/msp430.h` exists?

Comment: yes. in fact if I take second line of just-print output and execute separately file builds successfully.  I suspect this issue with how make rule for object is not working properly

Comment: if you see i am not refering g++ anyhwhere in makefile but some default rule is causing that line to execute.